# MySQL Federated table contains subset of data

Tags: mysql, federated-table

I've created a Federated table with MySQL and I've found that the local table that results only contain a subset of the data of the remote one.

This is the Federated:

```
CREATE TABLE `Activities` (
  `idActivity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Periods_idPeriod` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `applicationActivityId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `previousApplicationActivityId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` text,
  `ActivityTypes_idActivityType` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 4,
  `comment1` text,
  `comment2` text,
  `comment3` text,
  `Areas_idArea` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sentReports` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idActivity`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CONNECTION='mysql://admin:*******@*******:3306/sup_supperdb/Activities';
```

And this is the remote (original) one:

```
CREATE TABLE `Activities` (
  `idActivity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Periods_idPeriod` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `applicationActivityId` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `previousApplicationActivityId` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `title` text,
  `ActivityTypes_idActivityType` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `comment1` text,
  `comment2` text,
  `comment3` text,
  `Areas_idArea` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `sentReports` int(11) default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idActivity`),
  KEY `Activities_FKIndex1` (`Periods_idPeriod`),
  KEY `Areas_idArea` (`Areas_idArea`),
  KEY `ActivityTypes_idActivityType` (`ActivityTypes_idActivityType`),
  CONSTRAINT `Activities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Areas_idArea`) REFERENCES `Areas` (`idArea`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `Activities_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ActivityTypes_idActivityType`) REFERENCES `ActivityTypes` (`idActivityType`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `Activities_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Periods_idPeriod`) REFERENCES `Periods` (`idPeriod`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In the original one I get 3045 rows, but in the Federated only 2946.

If anybody has a hint on what may be happening or if is some kind of Federated tables limitations his comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Among the points to consider when FEDERATED storage engine is used ([15.8.3 FEDERATED Storage Engine Notes and Tips](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-usagenotes.html)), it is not mentioned anything about that kind of limitations.